# EKEvent is not following EKRecurrenceRule

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, eventkit

I am adding an event in iOS calendar using `EventKit`. The event is recurring event. I am setting recurring rules for the event programmatically. Event is getting added in calendar successfully but the dates shown on calendar are not same as I set them.

**Event details**
[image]

**Recurring rules.**
[image]

After event is successfully added to calendar this is what I get in calendar entry
[image]

My event is being show for 2017 but I didn't set the end date to 2017 it was 2016.

I tried adding the event with iOs calendar and got the same result.

Below is the code I am using.

```
/*!
 *  This method, called added event to the calendar
 */
- (void)addEventToCalendar
{
    @try {


        /* Event added to device calendar */
        [SINGLETON.eventStore requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
            if (granted) {

                [SINGLETON.event_Dateformat setDateFormat:[self dateFormatForSelectedLanguage]];
                EKEvent *event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:SINGLETON.eventStore];
                event.title = _event.eventTitle;
                event.startDate = [SINGLETON.event_Dateformat dateFromString:eventInfo.eventActualStartDate];
                event.endDate = [SINGLETON.event_Dateformat dateFromString:eventInfo.eventActualEndDate];
                event.notes = flattenHTML(eventInfo.eventDescription);

                // Get notification 2 hours before the event start time.
                [event addAlarm:[EKAlarm alarmWithRelativeOffset:-(2*60*60)]];
                [event setCalendar:[SINGLETON.eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];

                /* Here opening Event edit view controller */
                EKEventEditViewController *controller = [[EKEventEditViewController alloc] init];
                controller.event = event;
                controller.eventStore = SINGLETON.eventStore;
                controller.editViewDelegate = self;

                // Event is recurring mark it is repeat in calendar.

                // List of days on which a particular event occurs.
                NSMutableArray <EKRecurrenceDayOfWeek *> *daysOfTheWeek = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

                if (_event.eventRecurrence &&
                    ! [_event.eventDays containsString:@"N/A"]) {
                    for (NSString *dayName in [_event.eventDays componentsSeparatedByString:@","]) {
                        EKRecurrenceDayOfWeek *aDay = [EKRecurrenceDayOfWeek dayOfWeek:[self weekDayForDayName:dayName]];
                        [daysOfTheWeek addObject:aDay];
                    }
                }

                // When to stop reminding user for the event.
                EKRecurrenceEnd *endDate = [EKRecurrenceEnd recurrenceEndWithEndDate:event.endDate];

                EKRecurrenceRule *repeatRule = [[EKRecurrenceRule alloc] initRecurrenceWithFrequency:[self recurrenceFrequencey:_event.eventType] interval:1 daysOfTheWeek:daysOfTheWeek daysOfTheMonth:nil monthsOfTheYear:nil weeksOfTheYear:nil daysOfTheYear:nil setPositions:nil end:endDate];

                event.allDay = NO;

                 event.recurrenceRules = @[repeatRule];

                //[event addRecurrenceRule:repeatRule];

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                    //NSError *erroOnSave = nil;
                    // [SINGLETON.eventStore saveEvent:event span:EKSpanFutureEvents commit:YES error:&erroOnSave];
                    [MBProgressHUD hideAllHUDsForView:self.view animated:YES];
                    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
                });

            }else{
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    [MBProgressHUD hideAllHUDsForView:self.view animated:YES];

                [SINGLETON alertViewTitle:@""
                                  message:NSLocalizedString(@"Calendar setting alert", nil)
                              cancelTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", nil)
                                doneTitle:nil
                                      tag:0];
                    });

            }
        }];

    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        DLog(@"%@",exception);
    }
}
```

Below is the event details I get in debugger:

```
EKEvent <0x7f94b1f19d00>
{
     EKEvent <0x7f94b1f19d00>
{    title =        TBW   ; 
     location =     ; 
     calendar =     EKCalendar <0x7f94b439d280> {title = Calendar; type = Local; allowsModify = YES; color = #1BADF8;}; 
     alarms =       (
    "EKAlarm <0x7f94b4352fe0> {triggerInterval = -7200.000000}"
); 
     URL =          (null); 
     lastModified = 2016-04-25 05:18:27 +0000; 
     startTimeZone =    Asia/Kolkata (GMT+5:30) offset 19800; 
     startTimeZone =    Asia/Kolkata (GMT+5:30) offset 19800 
}; 
     location =     ; 
     structuredLocation =   (null); 
     startDate =    2015-09-20 18:30:00 +0000; 
     endDate =      2016-05-31 18:30:00 +0000; 
     allDay =       0; 
     floating =     0; 
     recurrence =   EKRecurrenceRule <0x7f94b43e7110> RRULE FREQ=WEEKLY;INTERVAL=1;UNTIL=20160531T183000Z;BYDAY=MO,TH; 
     attendees =    (null); 
     travelTime =   (null); 
     startLocation =    (null);
};
```

Please suggest what I am using wrong or I am missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution of this question with help of this answer

[iOS calendar is behaving strangly](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/237836/ios-calendar-is-behaving-strangly)

I was setting the **Ends** parameter in wrong way. It should be on same date as **Starts**. Time should be different.

Now my event screen looks like this

[image]